# Unbind hover on click

Tags: jquery, unbind

Given this code (`#stage` is an anchor tag with a div element inside it):

```
$('#stage').hover(

function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('div').stop().animate({
        'width': '70px',
        'height': '139px',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '-16px'
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('div').stop().animate({
        'width': '35px',
        'height': '70px',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '0px'
    }, 500);

});
```

(also found at http://jsfiddle.net/fXp9U/1/)

On click I need to stop the link taking me away from the page with a 'return false' and set the div as active. When you click, it shouldn't animate any more but should be the large size of the hover state.

If you remove the click event the hover works.

Thanks for you help again.

Comment: I've suggested an edit (should appear soon I would think) with your code. It's not that hard to just post your code to your question in addition to a fiddle, and you should do so.

Comment: `$( 'div', this ).stop()...` instead of what you have....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bind and unbind:

```
$('#stage').bind({
    'click': stage_onClick,
    'mouseenter': stage_onMouseEnter,
    'mouseleave': stage_onMouseLeave
});

function stage_onClick(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.unbind('mouseenter', stage_onMouseEnter);
    $this.unbind('mouseleave', stage_onMouseLeave);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function stage_onMouseEnter(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('div').stop().animate({
        'width': '70px',
        'height': '139px',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '-16px'
    }, 500);
}

function stage_onMouseLeave(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('div').stop().animate({
        'width': '35px',
        'height': '70px',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '0px'
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ronnie. The way you have set up the binds in the first function is new to me but will use in future projects.

Answer (score 0):

To unbind an event use `off()`, and to prevent the default action of a link (the `#stage` element in the linked [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXp9U/1/) (in the question body) *appears* to be an `a`, **not** a `div`):

```
$('#stage').hover(
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('div').stop().animate({
            'width': '70px',
            'height': '139px',
            'top': '0px',
            'left': '-16px'
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('div').stop().animate({
            'width': '35px',
            'height': '70px',
            'top': '0px',
            'left': '0px'
        }, 500);

    }).click(   
        function(e) {
            // prevents the default action of the link
            e.preventDefault();
            // animates the div element to the 'finished' position
            $(this)
            // unbinds the hover after a click
            .off('hover')
            // finds the child 'div' element, and prevents animation queueing
            // (just as it did in your original code)
            .find('div').stop()
            // animates the div element to the 'finished' position
            .animate({
                'width': '35px',
                'height': '70px',
                'top': '0px',
                'left': '0px'
            }, 500);
        });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fXp9U/6/).

References:

- [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).